# Convert database query result to json/yaml/xml with ABAP

Tags: abap

Is there a way to convert a database query result to json/yaml/xml with ABAP?

Answer (score 4):

```
    DATA: lt_flight TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF sflight,
          lrf_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_typedescr,
          lv_json   TYPE string.

        SELECT * FROM sflight INTO TABLE lt_flight.

        * serialize table lt_flight into JSON, skipping initial fields and converting ABAP field names into camelCase
        lv_json = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( data = lt_flight compress = abap_true pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case ).
        WRITE / lv_json.

        CLEAR lt_flight.

* deserialize JSON string json into internal table lt_flight doing camelCase to ABAP like field name mapping
/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize( EXPORTING json = lv_json pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case CHANGING data = lt_flight ).

* serialize ABAP object into JSON string
lrf_descr = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( lt_flight ).
lv_json = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( lrf_descr ).
WRITE / lv_json.
```

**Output**

```
[{"mandt":"000","carrid":"AA","connid":0017,"fldate":20130515,"price":422.94,"currency":"USD","planetype":"747-400","seatsmax":385,
"seatsocc":375,"paymentsum":192683.30,"seatsmaxB":31,"seatsoccB":31,"seatsmaxF":21,"seatsoccF":19},{"mandt":"000","carrid":"AA",
"connid....
{"ABSOLUTE_NAME":"\\TYPE=%_T00004S00000000O0000012480","ADMIN_TAB":"\\TYPE=%_T00004S00000000O0000012480",
"ADMIN_TAB_LINE":"\\TYPE=%_T00004S00000000O0000012480","DECIMALS":0,"HAS_UNIQUE_KEY":false,"INITIAL_SIZE":0,
"KEY":[{"NAME":"MANDT"},{"NAME":"CARRID"},{"NAME":"CO....
```

for more information please read [Serializer and Deserializer](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/One+more+ABAP+to+JSON+Serializer+and+Deserializer)

**UPDATE**

Another example:

First, you should create the `ABAP` to JSON Writer with the `CL_SXML_STRING_WRITER` with `Json as Type.`
Then Call the transformation to convert the String to JSON formatted String .
The last Step is to retrieve the Output of the Writer in JSON.

```
DATA text TYPE string VALUE `Hello JSON, I’m ABAP!`.
DATA writer TYPE REF TO cl_sxml_string_writer.
DATA json TYPE xstring.

    “ABAP to JSON
    writer = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
    CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE text = text
                            RESULT XML writer.
    json = writer->get_output( ).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just for the records, here is the documentation of "CALL TRANSFORMATION" https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_transformation.htm